# firebase logging best practice

Tags: firebase, logging, firebase-realtime-database

I'm looking for a way to log everything that is written on a firebase database. For now, I'm using a few firebase functions that are simply printing a diff between old values and new ones. However I'm not sure the firebase functions logs screen is the best tool in this situation. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: have a look at Crashlytics Events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way.
I'm still using firebase functions to log a diff of the previous and current values of objects written on my database.
I'm now using stackdriver logging from google cloud platform to visualize the logs, and this tool is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I ended up adding [database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) in which I send data to another firebase database (using the production one is not recommended) which stored the logs in the following form:

```
logs:{
   myFunction:{
      '10.01.2018': {
           debug: 'Some logging here',
           error: 'Some error here'
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: awesome, I'm also using database triggers, but I read them in stackdriver logging, so for this tool seems good to me. Are you loging everything manually or are you also using a 3rd party tool?